# Formatting a date based on a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash

How can I make my `backup_filename` function return a string (a filename) based on a passed-in date parameter?

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME="user_db"
FILENAME="${DBNAME}_%Y_%m_%d.pg"

backup_filename() {
    echo `$1 +"$FILENAME"`
}

BACKUP_FILENAME=$(backup_filename `date -d '2 days'`)
echo $BACKUP_FILENAME
```

This prints out the error `line 6: Sun: command not found`. I've tried different quoting strategies of `$FILENAME` but haven't had much luck.

Comment: If the line 6 is the `echo` line in the backup function definition, then try removing the back-quotes.

Comment: Your line 6 is using the first argument you sent to the function as a command, which is an error if you called the function with an argument of the output of the command you wished to run.  If you want an echo statement without implicit execution, try `echo "$1 + '$FILENAME'"` (note the single and double quotes).  If you want the function to do the execution, use `BACKUP_FILENAME=$(backup_filename "date -d '2 days'")` and then alter your function to call `echo "``$1`` +$FILENAME"` (using single instead of double back-quotes around `$1`).

Comment: I included the back ticks because I want to format the date argument using the format string defined in $FILENAME. If I don't include the back ticks, I get "Sun +user_db_%Y_%m_%d.pg" which isn't what I want.

Comment: Please specify the full command string that you wish the `date` function to be called with.

Comment: @abiessu date -d '2 days' +"user_db_%Y_%m_%d.pg"

Comment: I will defer to Dave S. in both his answer and his comment after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it should get you pretty close to what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME="user_db"
FILENAME="${DBNAME}"

backup_filename() {
    BACKUP_FILENAME="${FILENAME}_${1}"
}

backup_filename `date -d '2 days' +%Y_%m_%d`
echo $BACKUP_FILENAME
```

Comment: I'll be calling backup_filename from several different places, so I'd like it to handle formatting the date (whatever date it is given).

Comment: In that case just move the `date ...` stuff to inside the function.  Would that suffice?  If not, perhaps you want to pass in the "number of days ago" as the param.  What about that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script. It would work fine, you can change the format if you want. For a more customizable function, you pass the date format and the filename prefix as parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME="user_db"
FILENAME="${DBNAME}"
DATE_FORMAT="+%Y_%m_%d"

backup_filename() {
    BACKUP_FILENAME="${1}_"$(date -d "${2}" ${3})
}

backup_filename "$FILENAME" "2 days" "$DATE_FORMAT"
echo $BACKUP_FILENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Dave S. answer I ended up doing this.

```
#!/bin/bash
DBNAME="user_db"
FILENAME="${DBNAME}_%Y_%m_%d.pg"

backup_filename() {
    echo $(date -d "${1} days" +"${FILENAME}")
}

BACKUP_FILENAME=$(backup_filename 2)
echo $BACKUP_FILENAME
```